QGIS and constraints with groups
I will make two fields 'group' and 'group feature' with a constraints rule, where each group have no duplicate 'group feature' id. Each feature 1 till 3 will only once per group. How can I set up a constraint rule for grouping?

You already have features or do you want to apply this for when you create new features? Qhst have you tried?

both... I collect points on field and than I group them with "Group" field. And I give it a number in "Group feature" field. This number should only once in each "group".
